# Interrupting python import

Tags: python, exception, import, operating-system, interrupt

Due to some weird scenarios, I'm working on a server which has troubles importing tensorflow.

To be more specific if I try to import tensorflow, the server gets stuck, and I must interrupt the execution (by pressing Ctrl+C on my keyboard). After I interrupt it, everything works just fine and my program continues nicely. However, I would've liked this process to be automated, that is that after say two seconds through the import the python program would raise a "Ctrl+C" error by itself and will continue the flow.
I've tried to do this using python's signal library as follows:

```
import signal
import os

def raise_timeout(*a,**kw):
    print("tensorflow import timeout")
    raise KeyboardInterrupt
try:
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, raise_timeout)
    signal.alarm(2)
    import tensorflow as tf
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    #rest of my program
```

Rather weirdly this program prints "tensorflow import timeout" but doesn't stop.
Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So I actually solved this myself but I'll keep the post on in case anyone will encounter this problem in the future.
It appears that when python imports tensorflow, it creates a child process, tells it to import the library, and waits for its response. 
So what we need to do here is to kill our child process in the `raise_timeout` function.
I like doing this using the `psutil` library.
An optional syntax is as follows:

```
def raise_timeout(*a,**kw):
    print("timeout")
    current_process = psutil.Process()
    child = current_process.children(recursive=True)
    child[0].kill()
```

Assuming you have no other child processes this should work nicely, If anyone has any way to specifically select the correct child process or has any other improvement suggestion I would very much like to hear.

Comment: "It appears that when python imports, it creates a child process, tells it to import the library, and waits for its response" - that's definitely not a standard feature of the Python import system. I don't know if Tensorflow specifically creates any child processes, but the Python import system won't create child processes automatically.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, I edited my answer to be more accurate